# Firebase uses cloudfunctions.net instead of hosting rewrites rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have set up rewrites for named functions in firebase.json but still firebase.functions().httpsCallable() envokes [my-server].cloudfunctions.net/[function-name] instead of [my-server].com/

I am upgrading a current project that has been working fine with cloudfunctions.net, but I would like to limit the domain names being called because of some firewalls blocking that domain. 
Reading [the guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) if thought this addition in firebase.json would be sufficient:

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/getResponse",
        "function": "getResponse"
      }]
```

and then calling the function from my app with:

```
firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getResponse')
```

...But that envokes [my-server].cloudfunctions.net/getResponse instead of [my-server].com/getResponse

Opening [my-server].com/getResponse in my browser works, so I figure, there is some sort of explicit setting on firebase.functions() where I can force it to use custom domain?

Thanks you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to configure the Firebase client SDK for callable functions to invoke anything other than the default URL for the function.  If this is somehow important to you, you are free to [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: Thanks Doug. Reading the documentation I thought the default behaviour would be using custom urls once rewrites were set up. But, if firebase.functions().httpsCallable() keeps using the cloudfunctions.net URL is there no way to call custom URLs from local app - other than manually writing xhr requests?

Comment: Thank you for that link Doug, but I don't see how it answers if there is no way to call custom URLs from local app - other than manually writing xhr requests?

Comment: Yes, you can use the protocol description to write your own client.  If you're going to go through that trouble, though, maybe a callable isn't right for you, and an regular http function would be more appropriate.

Comment: OK thanks Doug. So I get that this is actually not supported for callables. I have filed a feature request for this.